# NG2 FormData add additional parameters that is not string

Tags: angular, angular-http, form-data

So, I have file upload and its working fine, but I need to add some extra parameters that are not strings.

This is how my method looks like now:

```
fileChange(event) {
        let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
        if (fileList.length > 0) {
            let file: File = fileList[0];
            let formData: FormData = new FormData();
            formData.append('url', file, file.name);
            formData.append('name' , 'JKANjksdnkjasd');

            let headers = new HttpHeaders();
            /** No need to include Content-Type in Angular 4 */
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
            headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
            // let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

            this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest_api/documents/', formData, {
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    'Authorization': 'jwt ' + this.localStorage.getToken()['token'],
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                })
            })
                .map(res => res)
                .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
                .subscribe(
                    data => console.log('success'),
                    error => console.log(error)
                )
        }
    }
```

Now, I would like to add a few more parameters, like this, but its not working

```
        formData.append('status' , 1);
        formData.append('type' , 1);
        formData.append('user' , 1);
```

formData.append() requires strings as parameters, I cannot add numbers. If I add those values as string, server is throwing me exception that primary key "1" cannot be found.

Any solutions for this?

Comment: Define not working please

Comment: The key point is that server is throwing an exception. You look at a wrong place

Comment: @smnbbrv The server is working correctly when doing it from postman or with other library in ng2, but I need to do it like this so I can have control over everything that is happening with input.

Comment: according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append `The field's value. This can be a USVString or Blob`. You will not be able to do anything else. Either adapt your server to server correctly or use another approach